# Image on website not displaying on iOS devices

Tags: html, ios, image, jpeg

I have a website where I also run a blog at http://climatecanchange.com/blog/ and the blogs are stored in a mysql database and each is matched to a unique image in one folder. I use php to get the image filename and other data to display all the blogs on my page.

For blog #2, my image is not showing on any iOS device (Chrome and Safari) though it can be seen on computers and Google Pixel too.

The link is http://climatecanchange.com/blog/blogs.php?id=2. When I open the image in a new tab it just shows white space. But, when I try to save it (on Chrome), it saves the actual image to my camera roll.

Can someone please help me with this? Why is there a problem with displaying that specific image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image format is Web/P which appears not to be supported in Safari right now

https://caniuse.com/#feat=webp

Comment: Oh, but isn't the pic in .jpg format >> http://climatecanchange.com/blog/images/diya-lights-off.jpg. Where does it indicate webp and how can I fix/convert it?

Comment: I downloaded it and ran `file` on it locally. The file extension doesn’t matter.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/325864/how-to-save-googles-webp-images-as-jpeg-or-png/

Comment: Ohh, got it. It's fixed now! Thanks a lot!